# Extract element from object of class "cpt" changepoint package

Tags: r

Package changepoint

I would like to extract from the below expression Slot "cpts": cpt 36  40 and can not figure out how to do it.

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,5,4,3,2,1,1,1)

cpt.meanvar(x,penalty="SIC",pen.value=0,method="AMOC",Q=5,test.stat="Normal")

An object of class "cpt"
Slot "data.set":
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 40 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 3 2 3 5 4 3 2 1 1 1

Slot "cpttype":
[1] "mean and variance"

Slot "method":
[1] "AMOC"

Slot "test.stat":
[1] "Normal"

Slot "pen.type":
[1] "SIC"

Slot "pen.value":
[1] 7.377759

Slot "cpts":
cpt     
 36  40 

Slot "ncpts.max":
[1] 1

Slot "param.est":
$mean
[1] 3.833333 1.250000

$variance
[1] 4.657143 0.250000

Slot "date":
[1] "Fri Apr 18 07:51:17 2014"
```

Have tried with

```
cpDxu2[[1]]
Error en cpDxu2[[1]] : this S4 class is not subsettable

cpDxu2$cpt
Error en cpDxu2$cpt : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

I would like to extract the coefficients cpt 36 40

On the other hand I seem not to find any instruction that maybe given in the package about extracting the different elements. Any help is welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (40 is not a change point, it is just the length of your data set)

```
cpts(cpDxu2)

#cpt 
#36
```

If you want it as a numeric object, do

```
as.numeric(cpts(cpDxu2))
```